# Saving bitmap file to server as jpg

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap, gdi+

I am trying to save the a bitmap file to jpg on my server, but unable to do so. I am able to save it to a stream and display it. But as soon as i try to save it to file it doesn't do anything. Below is my code, can someone tell me why its not saving to a file:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string jsonStr = Request.Form["output"];

            var sigToImg = new SignatureToImage();
            var signatureImage = sigToImg.SigJsonToImage(jsonStr);

            Bitmap bm2 = signatureImage as Bitmap;
            Bitmap bm3 = new Bitmap(bm2);

            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            //bm3.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg); If i use this it displays the image fine

            System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/Images") + "MyImage.jpg", FileMode.Create);
            bm3.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            bm2.Dispose();
            bm3.Dispose();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think part of your problem is that `Server.MapPath` is going to return a value that doesn't have a trailing directory separator. So your filename will be `"c:\whatever\ImagesMyImage.jpg"`. You need to add that intervening `"\"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in addition to disposing of the bitmap instances, you also close the file stream that you are writing to (after calling `bm3.Save()`):

```
fs.Close();
```

This flushes the stream out to disk and ensures that the image is actually contained in the file.

**---EDIT---**

As played out in the comments, this was due to `Server.MapPath` resolving to a directory that Brad didn't expect.

Comment: @BradHazelnut: Is it creating a file on disk at all? If not, it could be related to file permissions (i.e. check that the process is allowed to create files on disk).

Comment: I gave everyone permission full r/w permission on that folder just for testing and it doesn't create anything.

Comment: @BradHazelnut: Try hard-coding the file path of the image to be created instead of working it out using `Server.MapPath` in case that is resolving to somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: You're right that work, it was going to a different directory, i hard coded the path and it worked, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the save method within a try/catch block:

```
try
{
   bm3.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   // Check for errors here
}
```

Save can throw two types of exceptions:

`ArgumentNullException` filename or format is null.

`ExternalException` The image was saved with the wrong image format

I suspect the first one is occurring.

Comment: I tried adding this to my code, but no error or nothing,   try
            {
                System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/Images") + "MyImage.jpg", FileMode.Create);
                bm3.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception s)
            {
                
            }

Comment: Try this => bw3.FromStream(Response.OutputStream) THEN call the save function I listed above.

Comment: i get the following error when i try to add that line: System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(System.IO.Stream) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name reference instead